# Como acceder a proyectos sin host virtual teniendo activado virtual host?

Tags: php, xampp

No puedo acceder a proyectos que no tienen un host virtual teniendo activado Virtual hosts, y molesto tener que desactivarlo cada vez que quiera acceder a ellos.

Esto es lo que me sale cuando quiero entrar en un proyecto sin host virtual.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es recomendable usar espacios en URL porque te puede generar problemas como el que tienes ahora. Aparte, te faltó mencionar qué software de servidor estás usando (Wamp, Xampp, etc.) y la configuración de virtual hosts.

Comment: Uso xamp, el problema no es que tenga espacios en la url porque me pasa lo mismo con otros proyectos con url sin espacios, mi problema es que si tengo activado los virtual hosts en xampp solo puedo acceder a proyectos que tenga un host virtual y para acceder a los proyectos sin host tengo que desactivar virtual host y reiniciar apache

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código de `httpd-vhosts.conf`

Answer (score 0):

No soy ningún genio de este tema, pero quizás te sirva la configuración que uso en mi PC con XAMPP y Windows 10:

- Archivo `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`:

Con esta configuración consigo que al escribir en el navegador algo como `http://prueba.localhost` automáticamente se cargue lo que está en `C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba`, sin tener que agregar un bloque `<VirtualHost>` explícito para ese sitio.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

UseCanonicalName Off

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.localhost
    VirtualDocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/%1/"
</VirtualHost>
```

- Archivo `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`:

Peeeerooo... no todo es magia xD

Igual hay que agregar líneas en el archivo `hosts` del Windows para que al escribir `http://prueba.localhost` lo busque dentro de la propia máquina y no afuera.

```
127.0.0.1 prueba.localhost
127.0.0.1 otra-prueba.localhost
127.0.0.1 y-otra-prueba-mas.localhost
```

Si alguien sabe como mejorar esta parte, avise! :D